# How to copy random files to a specific folder?

Tags: command-line, copy

I have vast collection of files (6.5 million) in several folders and sub-folders and i want to copy some random picks (about 200k-300k files) to a directory to make a randomized sample.

the folder tree is this (just a small sample) inside each folder there are several files

```
.
├── articles.0-9A-B.txt
│   ├── 20_Century_Br_Hist
│   ├── 3_Biotech
│   ├── A_A_Case_Rep
│   ├── AAPS_J
│   ├── AAPS_PharmSciTech
│   ├── Abdom_Imaging
│   ├── Abdom_Radiol
│   ├── Abdom_Radiol_(NY)
│   ├── Acad_Emerg_Med
│   ├── Acad_Med
│   ├── Acad_Psychiatry
│   ├── Acad_Radiol
│   ├── Acc_Chem_Res
.
.
.
│   ├── Bull_Sci_Technol_Soc
│   ├── Bull_Volcanol
│   ├── Bull_World_Health_Organ
│   ├── Bundesgesundheitsblatt_Gesundheitsforschung_Gesundheitsschutz
│   ├── Burn_Res
│   ├── Burns
│   ├── Burns_Trauma
│   └── Bus_Soc
├── articles.A-B.xml
│   ├── 20_Century_Br_Hist
│   ├── 3_Biotech
│   ├── A_A_Case_Rep
│   ├── AAPS_J
│   ├── AAPS_PharmSciTech
│   ├── Abdom_Imaging
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally this would be a oneliner, but it may be a bad idea to process such a huge number of file(name)s directly, so I'll use a tempfile here.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
a=$(mktemp)
find /path/to/dir -type f | shuf -n $(shuf -i200000-300000 -n1) >$a
while IFS='' read -r l || [[ -n "$l" ]]; do
    cp "$l" /path/to/out/dir
done <$a
```

This will find every file located in `/path/to/dir`, shuffle them and save a random number of lines (between 200,000 and 300,000 as requested) of the output in tempfile `$a`. The `while` loop then just copies every file in the list to `/path/to/out/dir`.

---

Nonsense, we don't need a tempfile at all, we just pipe it to the `while` loop or – which I prefer – to `tr` and `xargs`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
find /path/to/dir -type f | shuf -n $(shuf -i200000-300000 -n1) |\
tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 cp -t /path/to/out/dir
```

This way you can even specify how many file names each invocation of `cp` should receive via `xargs`' `-n` option.